# Change in Redux-dev-tool means that Redux state is changed well?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'd like to ask a simple question.

If I fire `dispatch(action)` and `reducer` is reacted then,
 it is shown in redux-dev-tool like this

[image]

Can I say the `state` of `categoryName` in my `redux store` is updated well?

Comment: yup  redux dev tools is showing the _current_ state of redux ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I say the state of categoryName in my redux store is updated well?

Yes! You can!

For more information, you could read it here: [Redux Devtools for Dummies](https://codeburst.io/redux-devtools-for-dummies-74566c597d7)

[image]